# Prevent that Qt tooltip goes away on certain events like enter/leave or focus

Tags: qt, tooltip

I want to display a tooltip for a certain time, and want it to keep displaying its text for a specified duration ("The application has gone to fullscreen mode. Press [random key] to exit fullscreen mode").

However it turns out that the tooltip is always hidden immediately once my program goes to fullscreen mode. I suspect that's because of enter/leave events being sent, and Qt's tooltip listens to that and hides the tooltip in response.

How can I force the tooltip to stay open? Is there any other option besides implementing your own widget with a tooltip palette background? Or is the tooltip approach wrong altogether?

Comment: OpenGL based Windows?

Comment: @UlugToprak nope, normal qwidget

Comment: QQuickWidget triggers the same issue. you can set the WS_BORDER via Windows flag. setting a 1px border to full screen so other top level windows like the tool tip would stay on top

Comment: Classic behaviour of tooltip is the user doing a mouse-hover on something, so going full-screen while the user is _reading a tooltip_ does not sound user-friendly to me. And if the user actually does an action after displaying the tooltip, he is expecting the tooltip to disappear.

Comment: @ymoreau the intent was to use `QToolTip` to display a text. Like chromium's display "Use F11 to exit fullscreen" when you go to fullscreen mode. I guess tooltips are the wrong choice then?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb in my opinion you should make your own widget for that message yes, because the tooltip is usually expected by the user when pointing to a widget-control not as an information/warning banner. With your own widget you can control the layout, duration and behaviour more easily.

Comment: @ymoreau thanks. if you make it an answer, I will accept